# Remove the delete icon in a multi record block

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I am currently using Oracle APEX version 3.2.

How can I conditionally disable a record within many records in oracle apex 3.2
eg.

Example:

```
Icon          Id Number Description
Delete Icon   454545    Dog
Delete Icon   232323    Cat
Delete Icon   121321    Horse
```

I want to only delete a record when the description <> 'Cat'.
So, my question is, how can I either remove the (1) Delete icon from the Cat record or (2) disable the record so delete is not possible.

Also, please tell me where the code must be added.

Ideally I would like my screen to display the records as below:

```
Icon          Id Number Description
Delete Icon   454545    Dog
              232323    Cat
Delete Icon   121321    Horse
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this. try this one :

You can add new column in your sql (in report query) , set column type = Standart column

```
with ss as (select 454545 id, 'dog' animal from dual union all 
            select 232323 id, 'cat' a from dual union all
            select 121321 id, 'horse' a from dual)

 select id,
        animal,
        decode(animal,'cat','','<span class="delete-icon" animal-id="'|| id ||'">delete action<span>') as delete-act
  from ss
```

than, create dynamic action to catch click on icon (event=click, SelectionType = Jquery Selector, Jquery Selector =.delete-icon)

in dynamic action you must get data from clicked item and put it in your tmp_item PXX_TMP_ID (javascript), before this, you must create item on page (hidden, Value Protected = No)

```
$('#PXX_TMP_ID').val( $(this.triggeringElement).attr('animal-id').val() );
doSubmit('REQUEST_DELETE');
```

then create process "after submit" with conditions "REQUEST = REQUEST_DELETE" and put your code like

```
delete from your_table where id = :PXX_TMP_ID
```